# Temporarily zoom/expand/focus only current window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to focus/zoom the currently active editor by hiding all the other UI elements, splits, terminal and whatnot?

Kinda like zen-mode, but removing also any splits and full-screen-width.